# passing jsonarray from 1 activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, arrays

I am making an app in which I want o pass a json array between 2 activities .how to pass json arry from one activity to another through intents in android. can anybody help me over this??
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should convert JsonArray to String then attach it to Intent and send it.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("Your Json Response");
Intent obj_intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main1.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();                
b.putString("Array",jObject4.toString());
obj_intent.putExtras(b);
```

Where jObject4 is JSON Object.

Get in next Page :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String Array=b.getString("Array");
```

Comment: It's just passing JSONObject, not JSONArray.

Answer (score 59):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(your_activity.this, new_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("jsonArray", mJsonArray.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

**In the next Activity**

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String jsonArray = intent.getStringExtra("jsonArray");

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
            System.out.println(array.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("jsonArray", mJsonArray.toString());                                      what is mJsonArray here?

Comment: mJsonArray is the object of JSONArray